# Push_back on a vector of array of char

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a problem with push_back, it doesn't work with my code :(

```
    const int DIM = 10;
    vector<char[DIM]> categorie;

    int function_1(char cat[DIM]){
       categorie.push_back(cat);
       return 0;
    }
```

how can I resolve?

Thanks!

PS: I'm using Eclipse CDT

Comment: Resolve what? What is the problem that you have? How does the `push_back` not work? Please, add more info to your question. Do you have a compile error? Runtime crash? Unexpected results?

Comment: use `std::array` if possible.

Comment: This question is very clear, no additional info is necessary. In the code it shows a common misunderstanding among novices. People familiar with c++ can see the problem at first glance. Maybe this qustion phrasing sound silly, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392308 is even sillier still get 23 upvote. That question should be marked dup, for this question be canonical. @eerorika

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. `std::vector<T>` requires `T` to be copyable or movable. A plain array is neither. Note that inside `function_1`, `cat` is a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`.

If you have C++11, use `std::array`:

```
const int DIM = 10;
vector<array<char, DIM>> categorie;

int function_1(array<char, DIM> cat){
   categorie.push_back(cat);
   return 0;
}
```

If you don't have that, you'll have to wrap the array in a class and use that instead. Of course, [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/array.html) can do that for you.

Comment: This may be expensive since std::array is not movable so you will get two copy operations in some cases. Probably it is better to pass the array by const ref to `function_1`.

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, built-in arrays are rather odd creatures that can't be copied, assigned or passed by value; this makes it rather awkward to keep them in a container. Despite appearances, your function's parameter is actually a pointer, `char *`, so does not match the type expected by `push_back`. Even if you had an actual array, `push_back` wouldn't work, since it requires a copyable type.

If you're using C++11, then `std::array<char, DIM>` would be more convenient. Otherwise, you could wrap the array in a little class and store that.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

`int function_1(char cat[DIM]);` is not what you think.
it decays to `int function_1(char* cat);`
The correct syntax is `int function_1(char (&cat)[DIM]);`

**2.**

C-array are not copyable/moveable and `std::vector` requires at least one.

**3.**

You best option is to use `std::vector<std::array<char, Dim>>`.